# dynamically created button is does not show in mfc

Tags: mfc, cbutton

So I have this code

```
CButton details;
details.Create(_T("details"),WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|WS_TABSTOP|BS_PUSHBUTTON,CRect(120,100,100,30), this, 15000);
```

but it doesn't do anything(created button is not visible after creating it). What am I missing?

**EDIT:** The code is in a dialog based application's OnInitDialog function. What it should do is to display the button.

Comment: This question cannot be answered as it is. You need to provide more context. Where is `details` declared? Is it a class member? A local variable? Where are you calling `Create`? Consider providing an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that illustrates the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Your CButton is created with automatic storage duration. So it is destroyed when OnInitDialog returns. (Which is before the dialog is visible.)  Make the CButton a member variable instead.

Answer (score 0):

The values under `CRect` provided by you is incorrect, it must be `CRect(120, 100, 220, 130)`.

Answer (score 0):

this is depending to declaring `CButton details;`!
you must declare `CButton details;` as general instance(not local instance)

define your `CButton details;` instance as general, so your problem will solved!
bellow code work 100 percentage :

```
#define BBB 10000
CButton c;
void CThreadsDlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
    bool a = c.Create(_T("new button"), WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|BS_PUSHBUTTON, CRect(100, 100, 220, 230), this, BBB);
}
```

if `c` button created, `a` variable will be `true`.

Answer (score 0):

My experience: nothing is shown if your dialog is inherited from CDHtmlDialog, but works OK with normal CDialog. So change the first line in OnInitDialog()

```
//CDHtmlDialog::OnInitDialog();
CDialog::OnInitDialog();
```

and of course, the button variable should be global or class member, not local.